# PanelContainer does not change size according to its child

Tags: godot, gdscript

Godot 4.0.2
In my project I'm making a basic tooltip which can be applied to anything really. Move your mouse cursor over an object -> get a tooltip. Everything works fine, until the tooltip is displayed. Without playing with its `custom_minimum_size` all I get is a tall 1px wide line (basically, the contents of the `RichTextLabel` I use get squished inside the parent `PanelContainer` (at least, I assume it does that)). However, if I manually set the aforementioned `custom_minimum_size` of `PanelContainer` - things get displayed correctly, with one condition - I can't use `RichTextLabel.size` property for that. If I do, I get the same result as it was - tall 1px wide line. Oh, and the `RichTextLabel` is set to `fit_content`. I tried changing `RichTextLabel` `size_flag`s (tried every one) - didn't do anything.

In addition, if it matters:

- I create a new `PanelContainer`
- Add a `RichTextLabel` with necessary contents as a child
- Add `PanelContainer` as a child to the `get_tree().get_root()` (as I am testing it in a separate scene, the root is a `Control` node)
- and change its position as needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `RichTextLabel.autowrap_mode` to `TextServer.AUTOWRAP_OFF`.

The default for `RichTextLabel` is `AUTOWRAP_SMART` which does not play well with containers, resulting in 1px wide labels.

See [AutowrapMode](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_textserver.html#enum-textserver-autowrapmode) for the list of modes, others may fit better for your use case. You may need a combination of minimum size and autowrap mode for it to work as desired.

This can be done through gdscript with:

```
my_label.set_autowrap_mode(TextServer.AUTOWRAP_OFF)
```

Or in the node inspector:

[image: inspector settings]

Comment: Yep, that's the solution, thank you for pointing out Autowrapping. Never thought of looking there)